# Is there any way to sort the dataframe column which contain lists?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a column in a dataframe which contains list data

for example:

```
enter code here
| Column 1 | Column 2                  |
|--------- |---------------------------|
|    1     | ['jan']                   |
|    2     | ['jan','feb']             |
|    3     | ['feb','jan']             |
|    4     | ['mar','april','jan']     |
|    5     | ['jan','mar','april']     |
|    6     | ['jan','feb','mar']       |
|    7     | ['jan','feb','mar']       |
```

As in the above table we can see column 2, row 2 and row 3 have same list with different order. same is the case with other values too. like (row 4 and row 5)

I have to sort in this order

```
enter code here ['oct' ,'nov' ,'dec' ,'jan' ,'feb' ,'march' ,'april']
```

The desired output should be like below, a new column 3 with sorted values

```
enter code here
| Column 1 | Column 2                  |      Column 3             |
|--------- |---------------------------|---------------------------|
|    1     | ['oct']                   | ['oct']                   |
|    2     | ['oct','nov']             | ['oct','nov']             |
|    3     | ['nov','oct']             | ['oct','nov']             |
|    4     | ['mar','april','jan']     | ['jan','mar','april']     |
|    5     | ['jan','mar','april']     | ['jan','mar','april']     |
|    6     | ['jan','feb','mar']       | ['jan','feb','mar']       |
|    7     | ['jan','feb','mar']       | ['jan','feb','mar']       |
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sorted` by create dictionary with `enumerate`:

```
#import ast

#converted to lists if necessary
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

months = ['oct' ,'nov' ,'dec' ,'jan' ,'feb' ,'mar' ,'april']

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(months)}
   
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda y: d[y]))
print (df)
   Column 1           Column 2
0         1              [jan]
1         2         [jan, feb]
2         3         [jan, feb]
3         4  [jan, mar, april]
4         5  [jan, mar, april]
5         6    [jan, feb, mar]
6         7    [jan, feb, mar]
```

If values are first 3 letters is possible sorted by datetimes:

```
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda y: pd.to_datetime(y, format='%b')))
print (df)
   Column 1         Column 2
0         1            [jan]
1         2       [jan, feb]
2         3       [jan, feb]
3         4  [jan, mar, apr]
4         5  [jan, mar, apr]
5         6  [jan, feb, mar]
6         7  [jan, feb, mar]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @jezrael. First method is working, but why its not hashable, and what is 'ast' doing here. And in second case as we dont have the year info how it can bring oct, nov and dec before jan month. Oct, Nov and Dec are the previous year months. And jan, feb comes after it.